# Creating links, with categories and filters, ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in LinksController#create

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am really stuck and need some help. I am trying to create links that have categories and filters to them. When I'm trying to create a new link with categories and filter the website show the message that I've inserted.

I inserted most of the code, if I'm missing something please just comment and I will add it right away.

```html
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in LinksController#create
Level(#70251425229100) expected, got String(#70251404789620)

Extracted source (around line #27):

              
  # POST /links.json
  def create
    @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save

Rails.root: /Users/victorblomberg/startcode_co
```

```html
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:216:in `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:12:in `replace'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:123:in `level='
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `each_pair'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `each_pair'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:559:in `init_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:131:in `build_association'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:247:in `build_record'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:146:in `build'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:259:in `build'
app/controllers/links_controller.rb:27:in `create'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/Users/victorblomberg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/victorblomberg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/victorblomberg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Form.html.erb

```html
<%= form_for(@link) do |f| %>
  <% if @link.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@link.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @link.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>



<div class="form-group">
      <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {promt: "Choose a category" }, input_html: { class: "dropdown-toggle" } %>
      <%= f.collection_select :level_id, Level.all, :id, :name, {promt: "Choose a level" }, input_html: { class: "dropdown-toggle" } %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :subtitle %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :subtitle, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :company %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :company, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :websiteurl %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :websiteurl, :value => "http://", class: "form-control" %>

      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :linkcourse %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :linkcourse, :value => "http://", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :time %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :time, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :kind %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :kind, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :level %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :level, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sharefacebook %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :sharefacebook, :value => "http://", :target => '_blank', class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sharetwitter %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :sharetwitter, :value => "http://", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :cost %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :cost, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary"%>
      </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :links
end
```

link.rb

```html
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_votable
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :comments
 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :level
end
```

level.rb

```html
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :links

end
```

category.rb

```html
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :links

end
```

links_controller.rb

```html
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  # GET /links
  # GET /links.json
  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  # GET /links/1
  # GET /links/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /links/new
  def new
    @link = current_user.links.build
  end

  # GET /links/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /links
  # POST /links.json
  def create
    @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /links/1
  # PATCH/PUT /links/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.update(link_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /links/1
  # DELETE /links/1.json
  def destroy
    @link.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def upvote
     @link = Link.find(params[:id])
     @link.upvote_by current_user
     redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
     @link = Link.find(params[:id])
     @link.downvote_by current_user
     redirect_to :back
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_link
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
   def link_params
    params.require(:link).permit(:title, :subtitle, :company, :websiteurl, :linkcourse, :time, :kind, :level, :sharefacebook, :sharetwitter, :cost, :level_id, :category_id)
    end 
    
end
```

Comment: not sure why you are getting that error.  can you add `level_id` and `category_id` to permitted params?

Comment: I get this error: @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)

Comment: Do I need to add something to the create, beacuse I am getting this red mark: link = current_user.links.build(link_params)? 
links_controller.rb @jvnill

Comment: Please post your `model` code.

Comment: Just added the 3 different models. @Pavan

Comment: Can you post the `User` model too

Comment: Sure, there you go.Thanks in advance. @Pavan

Comment: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in LinksController#create
Level(#70251425229100) expected, got String(#70251404789620)
Extracted source (around line #27):
              
  # POST /links.json
  def create
    @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save


Rails.root: /Users/victorblomberg/startcode_co
Application trace:
app/controllers/links_controller.rb:27:in `create'

Comment: Why you have `level` attribute? i think it is conflicting with `level_id`.

Comment: Okay. I thought that was the issue as well, I will try to remove the attribute and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `level_id` and `category_id` in your `link_params`

```
def link_params
    params.require(:link).permit(:title, :subtitle, :company, :websiteurl, :linkcourse, :time, :kind, :level, :sharefacebook, :sharetwitter, :cost, :level_id, :category_id)
end
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in LinksController#create
 @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)

Comment: The only site on the website that dosen't work is the submit page. After you fill in the information on /links/new the submit page show ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch    @Pavan

Comment: @VictorBlomberg Do all the `attributes` in your `link_params` belongs to `link`?

Comment: @VictorBlomberg And also can you post full `error log`

Comment: Yes!
Do you want me to post the full trace on the error page? @Pavan

Comment: @VictorBlomberg Yes. Please Post.

Comment: @VictorBlomberg You are missed the main part. I want the error log from the beginning i.e., from the line which says `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`

Comment: @VictorBlomberg Please keep the remaining code as it is, don't erase

Comment: Just uploaded all again. Sorry for that.